# Gitlab error setting certificate verify locations

Tags: git, gitlab

I unexpectedly started receiving the folowing error on machine where gitlab runners is hosted. I entered 'git fetch --all' in PowerShell console

fatal: unable to access 'https://gitlab.domain/project.git/': error setting certificate verify locations:
CAfile: C:\Runners\MyRunner\builds\123xH2N\0\project.tmp\CI_SERVER_TLS_CA_FILE
CApath: none
error: Could not fetch origin

How can I solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try configuring Git to use Windows own Secure Channel library instead of OpenSSL? [git config http.sslBackend schannel](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-httpsslBackend), possibly with `--system` or `--global`.